# What is the general term for instruments without fixed pitches? Like fretless

Tags: terminology, instruments

There are fretless versions of electric guitars and basses. Instruments in the violin family are (almost) always fretless. But what is the general term for this when expanded for other instruments, like trombones, slide saxophones, theremins and other instruments that do not have fixed pitches?

Comment: What's an _almost fretless_ violin? Or, do you mean they're _almost always_ fretless? — A problem with this question is that it's hard to draw a clear line. Sure, piano and organ are 100% fixed-pitch and theremin is 100% continuous-pitch, but most other instruments have some sort of discrete choice built in yet can also perform more or less pronounced pitch bends and require fine-intonation by the player on each note. Striking example: [recorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recorder_(musical_instrument)), which with its holes one might think should be discrete, but really isn't.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think the OP had fretted violin in mind. It is not *almost fretless violin*, but *violins are (almost always) fretless*…

Comment: The examples instruments given are all of the real contiguous pitch type. Others are imaginable (piano with bend wheel?) which have the normal scale structure, but are capable of bridging the gaps. Shall they be included in the searched term?

Comment: @leftaroundabout  I interpreted that as referring to various antique or oddball families which are bowed and fretted as well --  nyckelharpa ,  Arpeggione , ...

Comment: BTW,  the slide saxophones I'm aware of use the slide to access open holes.  They aren't primarily capable of  continuous portamento

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I did not know this instrument before, but this one seems to be capable: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POzJoi463UI

Comment: Violins have one fret: the zeroth fret (nut) which frets the open string for you. So, almost fretless.

Comment: @Kaz You proved that musicians are as nerdy as programmers :D

Comment: @Kaz I think you're stretching a point (pun intended) to claim that requiring a node at both ends of the string constitutes a fret :-) .   One of the main differences, speaking from a physics point of view, between stringed instruments and wind instruments is that the wind instruments do not have a node at both ends (just essentially one at or near the mouthpiece), whereas  the thought of trying to generate a standing wave with a string that was open-ended.....

Comment: Interesting, I wonder how a violin where the nut was attached using a spring instead would sound. I guess each note would be bent in curious ways...

Answer (score 18):

I would suggest: [continuous pitch instruments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Continuous_pitch_instruments).

Comment: Interesting that it got a Wiki page!   Personally I don't see any value to grouping said instruments, but if it is helpful here and there, why not use it.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Well, it's a Category page, those are auto-generated on wikis anyhow.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft would there not be value in grouping such instruments for a composer working on microtonal music?

Comment: @kojiro  Not really, as any wind or string instrument can be "bent" to produce microtones.

Comment: I'd suggest hyphenating it for clarity: **continuous-pitch instruments**.

Answer (score 4):

The expression technique of producing a continuous tone while smoothly varying the pitch from one note to another is called *portamento*.

If we use the term *portamento instrument*, it's clear we are referring to a variable-pitch instrument that fundamentally supports portamento playing.

Comment: But a skilled player can, in fact, perform a portamento on a fretted/keyed instrument like a guitar or trumpet or clarinet. Being able to portamento on a certain instrument doesn't indicate that it doesn't have fixed pitches.

Comment: @NuclearWang I would say that these instruments do not *fundamentally support* portamento. If an instrument fundamentally supports portamento it means that a complete neophyte picking it up for the first time can obtain the effect easily, and that it can be easily applied to all or almost all of the notes of any melody, including large intervals as much as an octave or more.

Comment: @Kaz  a complete neophyte can't produce the correct note or effect on pretty much any instrument.  period.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft There are tons of counterexamples. Anyone can hit a key on a piano and get a tone. Or blow into a harmonica.  A toddler could blow into a slide whistle while moving the piston to produce a portamento from one pitch to another. That's what makes a slide whistle an example of an instrument which fundamentally supports portamento. You don't have to produce portamento *in spite* of the instrument's limitations; it is designed to produce it.